# Global Navigation - Unable to set permissions

Tags: 2010

SharePoint 2010

I'm site collection admin.

Problem: I'm unable to set permissions on global navigation links.

Example: I enter a user in the 'Audience' column, username validates. However, an error appears below stating "No exact match was found.  Click the item(s) that did not resolve for more options."  The name is underlined and validated but appears it doesn't think so?

I've tried this with user groups as well.

Comment: Have you tried with regular Audiences?  Is the User Groups SharePoint groups or AD security groups?

Comment: Also, have you tried the tip from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spblog/archive/2012/02/01/sps2010-post-sp1-aug-cu-target-audience-cannot-resolve-sharepoint-group-name-when-multiple-groups-share-a-common-string.aspx ?

Comment: Seems that issue should be resolved by patching SharePoint up to October 2012 CU http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687545